# Remove unremovable property of a file in Windows

Tags: file, properties

I have a picture, edited with Photoshop. When I right-click on the file and select Properties -> Details, as one of the properties stands the origin of the file, but unlike most of other properties, this property cannot be removed. Google says:

> The Remove Properties dialog box only
>   removes properties that were added
>   using Windows. If you added properties
>   using a different program, you must
>   remove those properties using that
>   program.

How can I modify/remove such a property, not added by Windows? Is it possible to do this with Java code and how exactly can I access the properties of a file with Java?

Comment: what property are you trying to remove?

Comment: Yes, they are Jpeg. I solved my problem, opening the image with Paint, drawing almost invisible point and saving the modified image as .bmp, opening it again and saving it as .jpg. But the question is still interesting to me.

Comment: Image quality may suffer when you save to JPEG many times, especially with Paint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XnView. It can delete these properties even in batch mode. I don't have this software right now but Google says you need Batch Processing -> Image -> Clean Metadata

Also, in Photoshop you can use "Save for Web" instead of "Save", and in settings window choose Metadata: No metadata